# Pristine does not detect form inside form (directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have a form with some input, and then a button that open a directive a modal popover where there is another form. the pristine state does not detect the changes in the directive.
How to solve this?

```
 <form name="createFeeForm"
        <input....
        <input....
        {{show the data from the something-popover}}
        <something-popover....</something-popover>
        <button ng-disabled="createFeeForm.$pristine">SAVE & CLOSE</button>
 </form>
```

for the directives template.html

```
<form name="somethingForm">
      <input...
      <input...
      <button ng-disabled="somethingForm.$pristine">SAVE & CLOSE</button>
</form>
```

The parent pristine will detect all input changes on input tag, except for the directive

Comment: You probably shouldn't have your modal form nested inside another form. This would be invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, and I couldn't trigger any kind of form behavior when it was a form inside another form (I wasn't using a directive, it was directly on the same file).

I'm using something like this:

The form triggers a modal id on href (in my case, I need to pass an Id, so I used a function for it):

```
<a data-toggle="modal" ng-click="passId(id)" href="#modalDirective">Open Modal</a>
```

and then, outside the form, you add the directive (usually I do it on the end of the page):

```
</form>
<something-popover....</something-popover>
```

When the page renders, Angular will load the template and the modal will be accessible, and yopu will have two separeted forms that you can handle.

Hope it helps!